# WP All Import - set correct URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I need to set correct URL on imported by WP All Import pages, but when I set permalinks in Worpdress to %postname% wpallimport crops it to about 40 chars (I use cyrillic post names), so it can't import all posts because of error "Duplicate records detected during import".

I also tried to import with default permalinks (%post_id%) then change guid in database, but had some issues.

If I create post with %post_name% in URL by myself URL it's fine.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out there is "Post Slug" in "Other Post Options". It's still cut cyrillic, but I transliterated post titles to latin and it works well